# SQL SELECT SUM from two tables and GROUP BY date

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum, subquery

I have two tables (`rescues` and `counts`) with one to many relationship in a MySQL 5.1 database.
There could be multiple rows in `rescues` with the same datetime. In `counts` there is at least one row (ore more) associated to `rescues` (rescues.id = counts.id_rescue).

I want to get:

- the sum of a column in "rescues"
- the sum of some columns in "counts"
- the sum of a column in "counts"
- group the results by date

This is what I am doing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9a290/2/0

I get these results (wrong `sum_volounteers` but correct `sum_alive` and `sum_dead`):

```
date        sum_volounteers   sum_alive   sum_dead
2014-02-02  5                 138         18
2014-02-04  4                 53          15
```

What I am expecting is:

```
date        sum_volounteers   sum_alive   sum_dead
2014-02-02  11                138         18
2014-02-04  5                 53          15
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to `SUM()` the volunteers on the outer query:

```
SELECT
r.date,
sum(r.sum_volounteers) AS sum_Volunteers,
sum(c.males + c.females + c.uncertains + c.couples*2) AS sum_alive,
sum(c.roadkills) AS sum_dead
FROM counts AS c
JOIN(
  SELECT
  r2.id AS selected_id,
  sum(r2.volounteers) AS sum_volounteers,
  CAST(r2.start AS DATE) AS date
  FROM rescues AS r2
  GROUP BY selected_id
) AS r ON c.id_rescue = r.selected_id
WHERE r.date >= '2014-02-02' AND r.date <= '2014-02-04'
GROUP BY r.date
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9a290/7/0)

Since you were only grouping on the date, MySQL was just picking one of the `sum_volunteers` values to return from your subquery, while there were multiple for that date.

Comment: +1, This is the correct answer.  Just `SUM` the `SUM` from the subquery.

Comment: Results are still wrong, I figured out that the solution is to `SUM(DISTINCT r.volounteers)` in the outer query. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @AlbertoRighetto without the expected results I didn't know what I was after, glad you added that in.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found a problem using this query, if there are two ore more rows in `rescues` with the same number in the column `rescues.volounteers` the results are wrong. See my other answer for the correct solution.

<strike>Thanks to other comments I figured out that I needed to `SUM(DISTINCT r.volounteers)` on the outer query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9a290/69/0</strike>

Using `SUM()` in the subquery is not required.

```
SELECT
r.date,
sum(DISTINCT r.volounteers) AS sum_volounteers,
sum(c.males + c.females + c.uncertains + c.couples*2) AS sum_alive,
sum(c.roadkills) AS sum_dead
FROM counts AS c
JOIN(
  SELECT
  r2.id AS selected_id,
  r2.volounteers AS volounteers,
  CAST(r2.start AS DATE) AS date
  FROM rescues AS r2
  GROUP BY selected_id
) AS r ON c.id_rescue = r.selected_id
WHERE r.date >= '2014-02-02' AND r.date <= '2014-02-04'
GROUP BY r.date
```

Now I'm getting correct results:

```
date        sum_volounteers   sum_alive   sum_dead
2014-02-02  11                138         18
2014-02-04  5                 53          15
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to select `SUM(r.volounteers) AS sum_volounteers` in the outer query, then in the subquery get `sum_alive`, `sum_dead` and `date_of_sums` (using a `JOIN` in the subquery) and `GROUP BY date_of_sums` then `JOIN c.date_of_sums = CAST(r.start AS DATE)`

The other query I posted fails when a record is added in `rescues` with the same number in the column `rescues.volounteers`, this is the correct one:

```
SELECT
   r.id,
   CAST(r.start AS DATE) AS date,
   SUM(r.volounteers) AS sum_volounteers,
   sum_alive,
   sum_dead
FROM rescues AS r
JOIN(
   SELECT
   CAST(r2.start AS DATE) AS date_of_sums,
   sum(c2.males+c2.females+c2.uncertains+c2.couples*2) AS sum_alive,
   sum(roadkills) AS sum_dead
   FROM counts AS c2
   JOIN rescues as r2
   ON r2.id = c2.id_rescue
   GROUP BY date_of_sums
  ) AS c
ON c.date_of_sums = CAST(r.start AS DATE)
WHERE
   CAST(r.start AS DATE) >= '2014-02-02'
   AND CAST(r.start AS DATE) <= '2014-02-04'
GROUP BY CAST(r.start AS DATE)
```

Here's a demo:

- correct query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cc1eb/77
- <strike>wrong (old) query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/efd26/1/0</strike>

This query gives the correct result:

```
date        sum_volounteers   sum_alive   sum_dead
2014-02-02  11                138         18
2014-02-04  9                 73          23
```